# Matplotlib showing two empty figures

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I was trying to plot 2 seaborn plots near each other, however it results in:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20,8))
sns.jointplot(df['target'], df['bedrooms'], alpha=0.5,color='r', ax=ax1)
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.xlabel('Price')
plt.ylabel('Number of bedrooms')


sns.jointplot(df['target'], df['bathrooms'], alpha=0.5, color='b', ax=ax2)
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.xlabel('Price')
plt.ylabel('Number of bathrooms')

plt.show()
```

And as output I have:
[image]
Two empty figures and then in column my two plots

Comment: You need to remove `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20,8))` because `sns.jointplot` is a figure-level function that creates its own figure. The `height=` parameter controls its size.  Only square jointplots are supported.  If you really want, you can change the figure size afterwards.

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQs)#why-isnt-seaborn-drawing-the-plot-where-i-tell-it-to